# Можно ли делать так ,чтоб PHP работал асихронно?

Tags: php, асинхронность

Я как то слышал что Facebook мог сделать асинхронные запросы к БД с помощью PHP , возможно ли такое ? 
 Если да то как?

Comment: А что конкретно вы подразумеваете под асинхронными запросами к БД, а что под синхронными? Простите конечно за любопытство:).

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв.
Тоисть сохранить или получать данные с БД по несколькими потоками как это делается в NodeJs.

Comment: Раз FB, то скорее не php, а [HHVM](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.async.php). А в php вас [это](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.poll.php) интересует?

Comment: @ВОРОН скорее всего вы правы по поводу  HHVM. Спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если многопоточность на бэкэнде, то можно. Запустить несколько форков (воркеров), каждый из которых будет самостоятельно выполнять запросы к БД. Для создания нескольких форков можно воспользоваться функцией [`pcntl-fork`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-fork.php). Может еще понадобится `posix_getpid` для получения pid процесса.

При обработке http-запроса от пользователя асинхронно выполнять запросы не знаю как. Думаю, что в php нет такой функциональности. Ведь нужно не просто выполнять запросы, а и следить за их статусом - выполнен/не выполнен. А, затем, вернуть ответ пользователю.

Comment: Я вас правильно понимаю: для работы с БД вы предлагаете создать кучу(пул) подключений с помощью которых несколько(куча) потоков будут независимо друг от друга "общаться" с БД?

Comment: Спасибо большое, я думаю мне сейчас и pcntl_fork-а хватит для иследования.)

Comment: форк это НЕ многопоточность

Comment: @barmaglott, да, каждый форк должен установить свой коннекшен с БД. Несколько коннекшенов вместо одного, зато это позволяет распараллелить вычисления. Не вижу в этом ничего критичного, тем более ещё можно включить persistent connections. Насколько знаю, обычно воркеры так и работают.

Comment: @Etki может вы и правы, но эмулировать многопоточность форки позволяют. http://habrahabr.ru/post/148688/ По крайней мере запросы к БД будут выполняться параллельно, на мой взгляд это и есть многопоточность.

Comment: @jekaby многопоточность это НЕ параллельное исполнение

Answer (score 1):

В этом вам поможет [pcntl-fork](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-fork.php) вместе с [ReactPhp](http://reactphp.org). Запускаете php как демона, проксируете через [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com) и радуетесь жизни. Единственное что, нужно написать свой PPM что бы все ядра задействовать. Статья на тему [PPM](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148596/)

Answer (score 0):

При обработке http-запроса от пользователя асинхронно выполнять запросы к mysql PHP умеет начиная с 5 версии, то есть, уже больше 10 лет.

Другое дело, что внятно сформулировать - зачем им такие запросы, и каким образом они собираются их использовать- подавляющее большинство спрашивающих не могут.

Comment: Честно говоря я хочу глубоко изучать PHP  , я работал с ним но  2 года назад, мало что помню, теперь снова хочу вернутся , но как бы я эти 2 года работал на Node.js и привык асинхронному коду. 
Хотел узнать какие асинхронные способности есть у PHP.